# .First function in R

Tags: r

I don't understand the point of .First function in R. My reason is any code in .Rprofile will be sourced and executed when R starts up anyway.

this

```
.First<-function(){                                                                 
    library('devtools')                                     
}
```

and this

```
library('devtools')
```

in .Rprofile have exactly the same effect.

However, here is an example that shows .First can make a difference:

example 1, you can see X11.options()$type correctly becomes Xlib as set in .Rprofile

```
>> cat .Rprofile
.First <- function() {
    library(devtools)
}

setHook(
    packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
    function(...) grDevices::X11.options(type="Xlib")
)

>> Rscript -e 'X11.options()$type'
[1] "Xlib"
```

example 2, you can see X11.options()$type is still cairo, the setHook in .Rprofile didn't take effect

```
>> cat .Rprofile
library(devtools)

setHook(
    packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
    function(...) grDevices::X11.options(type="Xlib")
)

>> Rscript -e 'X11.options()$type'
[1] "cairo"
```

- in what case do I absolutely have to use .First function?
- why .First made a difference in the example above?

Thanks!

Comment: You can save `.First` function in `.RData` I guess. R first loads the `.Renviron` file then `.Rprofile` file and then `.RData` file. So if you save `.First` function in `.RData`, you can define different `.First` function for each project. I think that should be the purpose of having `.First` function.

Comment: @Narendra. OK, I'm convinced. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Narendra More or less the help file: *A function .First (and .Last) can be defined in appropriate ‘.Rprofile’ or ‘Rprofile.site’ files or have been saved in ‘.RData’.*

Comment: @Narendra Thanks for clearing this up. I've made a small example in the original post to show .First can sometimes make a difference, but I do not understand why.

Comment: See if you change `action` to `attach` both versions will return `Xlib`. Note that `.Rprofile` is sourced before execution of `.First`. So this is happening in your first version: `.Rprofile` defines the hook and then the namespace is loaded when `.First` and `.First.sys` are executed . So here hook configuration works. In second version: `.Rprofile` loads namespace  of `grDevices` before hook is defined. So the hook is useless in second version. The package namespace is never *loaded* again and hence it runs `cairo`.

Comment: Now let's see why *attach* returns *Xlib*. Version1 : Hook defined in `.Rprofile` then packages attached by `.First` and `.First.sys` so hook works and hook config are initialized. Version 2: Package attached by `.Rprofile` and then hook defined by `.Rprofile` and then packages attached again by `.First.sys` and then hook runs for the first time. So hook config are initialized again.

Comment: @Narendra regarding second version, you say ".Rprofile loads namespace of grDevices before hook is defined.", But I think grDevices is loaded in .First.sys(), which is after .Rprofile is sourced? unless the `library(devtools)` call also loads `grDevices`.

Comment: You've `library(devtools)` in second version. This command also loads `grDevices` becuase `devtools` uses this package. (If you try `detach(package:grDevices, unload  = T)` in R prompt in second version, you'll get an error saying devtools uses grDevices.). So, `.First.Sys`, which is executed after `.Rprofile` and `.First` (in this case there is no `.First`), loads all default packages. But `grDevices` is already loaded. So now `.First.Sys` loads rest of the default packages only. Note that loading and attaching are different things and so are unloading and detaching.

Comment: Thanks!! all clear now. it turned out devtools imports stats, and stats imports grDevices

Answer (score 1):

It may be unnecessary but it does provide yet another place to modify the startup. It certainly doesn't hurt having it.

I generally run R in different directories to keep things separated;  link to a common .Rprofile; and use .First to tailor the current R run environment to the specific problem I'm working on. If .First action wasn't available I'd have to create one.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of putting startup code in .First() instead of .RProfile is that you can use local variables which won't stay in your Global environment after .First() completes.

For example, my .First() displays the list of .R files on the project directory in as many columns as will fit:

```
localFiles <- list.files(pattern = "\\.R$", ignore.case = TRUE)
maxChars <- max(nchar(localFiles))
numCols <- as.integer((options("width")$width-2) / (1 + maxChars))  # how many columns will fit?
fmt <- sprint(" %%-%d", maxChars)                  # left justified in each column
for (nn in localFiles) {
  if ((match(nn, localFiles) %% numCols) == 1) cat(" ")   # indent each row
  cat(sprint(fmt, nn))
  if ((match(nn, localFiles) %% numCols) == 0) cat("\n")  # end of row
}
if (length(localFiles) %% numCols != 0) cat("\n")         # end last row if not complete
```

Since this is in .First(), all of the temporary variables get cleaned up when the function returns and the Global environment remains clean.

Answer (score 0):

R sources `Rprofile.site` then either project-level or user-level `.Rprofile` and then evaluates `.First` ([Rstudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf)).

`.First` is useful to include in `Rprofile.site` if you want to trigger an action (site-wide) that is conditional on user or project `.Rprofile`.

Example:  `renv` is activated by project-level `.Rprofile`.

This code will print a message indicating the location of the `renv` cache or will alert the user that `renv` hasn't been activated.

```
if (interactive()) {
  .First <- function() {
    if ("RENV_PROJECT" %in% names(Sys.getenv())) {
      cat("\nLinked to renv cache:\n")
      cat("-", renv::paths$cache(), "\n\n")
    } else {
      cat("\n***  Warning:  you are not in an active renv project! ***\n")
      cat("- Some functions may be unavailable.\n\n")
    }
  }
}
```