# First function blocking a project opening

Tags: r

I've just read this post: [.First function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356603/first-function-in-r) as I have previously used the first function when instructed for a short online course in which script was shared and run through with attendees. I don't fully understand much in the post or the use of the first function (I'm a relative beginner), but I think it is related to an error message every time I try to open up a project in R studio, and the project won't open and the session won't close. I can still open the project directly from the Rproject file, but would like to get rid of this issue.

The error in the console is :
Error in ll(class = c("matrix")) : could not find function "ll"

Has something been overwritten in Rstudio? Could someone advise as to how to get rid of this?
Many thanks.

Comment: I've just overcome part of the problem using information from this post in the rstudio community: https://community.rstudio.com/t/reset-the-list-of-packages-back-to-initial-installed-state/23720

Comment: Plus I found that r scripts are also referred to as source documents in R studio, which I need to have clicked on to restore. I still have my .RData file unlinked but it doesn't seem to be needed for my project . Need to read up on the requirements and use of .RData.